# Importing specific package version

Tags: npm

I'm trying to use bower the package management to add new modules to my project.
 I am using travis for continuous integration
Travis CI throws an error

```
error: pathspec '2.4.1' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

This is issued by the keyboardjs module with 2.4.1 version, not sure what would be the optimal workaround this? If you check the package.json of the keyboardjs [Github](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/KeyboardJS/blob/master/package.json#L4) It's using the version 2.4.1 aswell.

My package json line for the 2.4.1 version of keyboardjs

```
@bower_components/keyboardjs": "RobertWHurst/KeyboardJS#2.4.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

What is contained in the `package.json` file is irrelevant. If you are using a git URL you have to provide something that references a commit.

You can see on the [tags page](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/KeyboardJS/tags) that the tag is called `v2.4.1`. So:

```
RobertWHurst/KeyboardJS#v2.4.1
//                      ^
```